# Spring boot not able to connect mysql in kubernetes cluster

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, kubernetes

In kubernetes cluster Spring boot application not able to connect mysql on more than one containers.

Ex. I have Mysql Container Running and i have spring boot application which connect to mysql container, everything works fine if i have one spring boot application

[image]

But if i scale the Spring boot component to ex 4 pods then one of them will not be able to connect to mysql container

Please help on this

**Logs**

```
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:91) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
        at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:144) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:850) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
        ... 58 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: some-mysql
```

**Kubernetes Mysql Deployment File**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mysql-pv
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: standard
  capacity:
    storage: 250Mi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:                       
    path: "/mnt/data"
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
--- 
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim 
metadata:                          
  name: mysql-pv-claim
  labels:
    app: practice-app
spec:                              
  storageClassName: standard
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce                
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 250Mi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: some-mysql
  labels:                         
    app: practice-app
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 3306
  selector:                       
    app: practice-app
    tier: mysql
  clusterIP: None
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment                    
metadata:
  name: some-mysql           
  labels:                           
    app: practice-app
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:                    
      app: practice-app
      tier: mysql
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:                         
    metadata:
      labels:                       
        app: practice-app
        tier: mysql
    spec:                           
      containers:
      - image: mysql:5.6            
        name: mysql
        env:                        
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD 
          valueFrom:                
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mysql-root-pass
              key: password
        - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mysql-db-url
              key: database
        - name: MYSQL_USER
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mysql-user-pass
              key: username
        - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mysql-user-pass
              key: password
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306        
          name: mysql
        volumeMounts:
        - name: mysql-persistent-storage  
          mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
      volumes:                       
      - name: mysql-persistent-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mysql-pv-claim
```

**Kubernetes Spring Boot Deployment file**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1           # API version
kind: Deployment              # Type of kubernetes resource
metadata:
  name: order-app-server    # Name of the kubernetes resource
  labels:                     # Labels that will be applied to this resource
    app: order-app-server
spec:
  replicas: 1                 # No. of replicas/pods to run in this deployment
  selector:
    matchLabels:              # The deployment applies to any pods mayching the specified labels
      app: order-app-server
  template:                   # Template for creating the pods in this deployment
    metadata:
      labels:                 # Labels that will be applied to each Pod in this deployment
        app: order-app-server
    spec:                     # Spec for the containers that will be run in the Pods
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: testXxxxxsecret
      containers:
      - name: order-app-server
        image: XXXXXX/order:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080 # The port that the container exposes

        env:                  # Environment variables supplied to the Pod
        - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME # Name of the environment variable
          valueFrom:          # Get the value of environment variable from kubernetes secrets
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mysql-user-pass
              key: username
        - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mysql-user-pass
              key: password
        - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mysql-db-url
              key: url
---
apiVersion: v1                # API version
kind: Service                 # Type of the kubernetes resource
metadata:                     
  name: order-app-server-service    # Name of the kubernetes resource
  labels:                     # Labels that will be applied to this resource
    app: order-app-server
spec:                         
  type: LoadBalancer              # The service will be exposed by opening a Port on each node and proxying it. 
  selector:
    app: order-app-server   # The service exposes Pods with label `app=polling-app-server`
  ports:                      # Forward incoming connections on port 8080 to the target port 8080
  - name: http
    port: 8080
```

**Spring boot application yml**

```
spring:
  application:
     name: order-service

  datasource:
     url: jdbc:mysql://some-mysql:3306/practicecommerce?autoReconnect=true&failOverReadOnly=false&maxReconnects=10&useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
     username: prac
     password: prac


  jpa:
    hibernate:
      naming:
        physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
      ddl-auto: update

    properties:
      hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    show-sql: true

server:
  port: 8080
```

Comment: mysql and all spring boot pods are in same namespace?

Comment: yes all are in default namespace

Comment: Based on the description of problem during scaling, I would guess that one of the Nodes has a CNI misconfiguration, or isn't running kube-proxy (the component responsible for the management of those `Service` constructs via iptables rules). Separately, it's highly suspicious that you have a `Service` with `clusterIP: None` in a `Deployment` since those "headless" services are used with StatefulSet (which you should be using anyway for a database, but that's beside the point for your current question)

Comment: How many nodes does your cluster have? If you scale the spring deployment to more for example 6 how many are not working?

Comment: @Crou If i scale to 6 nodes then 5 will be available and 1 keeps on restarting due to able mention error. I tried with 4 nodes also, in that case 3 will be available and 1 keeps restarting

Comment: @mdaniel Initially i started with 1 pod which works fine, once i scale the one of the pods will keep on restarting.

Comment: You are scaling deployment not nodes, show output of `kubectl get nodes` also can you show the events all pods within the deployment?

Comment: I have answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/63710212/9041053 . Hope it helps.

Comment: something new? I have a same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70682733/access-internal-database-in-cluster-with-local-application#comment124959530_70682733