# Access internal database in cluster with local application

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, minikube

I try to connect a local spring boot application with an internal mysql-db in k8-cluster.
I used the k8 cluster locally in docker desktop.

My deployment.yml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: kazi-db
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: mysql/mysql-server:8.0
          name: mysql
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          env:
            - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: kazi-db-secret
                  key: password
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3306
              name: mysql
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mysql-persistent-storage
              mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
      volumes:
        - name: mysql-persistent-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: mysql-pv-claim
        - name: mysql-initdb
          configMap:
            name: kazi-initdb
```

my service.yml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kazi-db
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 3306
  selector:
    app: kazi-db
  type: LoadBalancer
```

The service description:

```
kubectl get services kazi-db     
NAME      TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kazi-db   LoadBalancer   10.107.75.107   localhost     3306:31627/TCP   3d
```

my spring-boot application.yml

```
## JDBC part
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: local
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/kazi?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
    username: emo
    password: 123qwe
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
  liquibase:
    change-log: classpath:liquibase/changelog.xml
```

I used localhost because k8 has a localhost as externalIp defined.

```
kubectl describe services kazi-db
Name:                     kazi-db
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=kazi-db
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP Families:              <none>
IP:                       10.107.75.107
IPs:                      <none>
LoadBalancer Ingress:     localhost
Port:                     <unset>  3306/TCP
TargetPort:               3306/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  31627/TCP
Endpoints:                <none>
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age   From                Message
  ----    ------  ----  ----                -------
  Normal  Type    10m   service-controller  ClusterIP -> LoadBalancer
```

I have a local mysql-db too an i can connect the application without problems.
I can connect to the db-cluster with `kubectl exec -it kazi-db-554bd6d787-2gb88  -- /bin/bash`  an create some table, but the application not.

When i start the spring-boot application:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'kazi'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
```

although the db kazi exists in db-cluster.

But how i have to connect to internal k8 cluster db?

I'm using docker desktop `v20.10.11` with k8s `v1.22.4`. I tried it with `minikube version: v1.24.0` too. Of both, i have the same issue.

Comment: `Unknown database 'kazi'` - no such database in the mysql instance that you try to connect?

Comment: The problem isn't the db but the connection. The DB exists in mysql cluster k8, but how to connect local spring boot with mysql in k8 cluster.

Comment: Hold-on, change the data source from url: jdbc:mysql://`localhost:3306` to url: jdbc:mysql://`localhost:31627`

Comment: @gohm'c done but `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure`

Comment: Use this command to get  the minikube IP and a service NodePort: `minikube service --url kazi-db`. Then change the data source to this url.

Comment: Hi, @emoleumassi were you able to solve your issue? If not can you share more details about your k8s cluster environment?

Answer (score 1):

i resolve it with port forwarding: `kubectl port-forward <pod-name> 3306:3306 -n default`